# web scraping next page

Tags: web, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have a problem trying to web scrape some data from various pages. I've tried to Google some solutions, but didn't work at all.

My point is web scrape just the names of the Graphics cards from this website: "https://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=StoreIM&IsNodeId=1&bop=And&Depa=1&Category=38&Page=2&PageSize=12&order=BESTMATCH"

In the first place, I tried to build a code that works just with one of the pages. And that works pretty well.

```
    from urllib2 import urlopen as uReq
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
    import requests
    import re

    my_url = "https://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=StoreIM&IsNodeId=1&bop=And&Depa=1&Category=38&Page=2&PageSize=12&order=BESTMATCH"
    uClient = uReq(my_url)
    page_html = uClient.read()
    uClient.close()
    page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

    containers = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"item-container"})
    container = containers[0]

    for container in containers:
        title_container = container.findAll("a",{"class":"item-title"})
        product_name = title_container[0].text
        print("product_name: " + product_name)
```

########
With this, I got the names of the Graphic Card at the page 2. If I switch it to 1 at the HTML I can get the names of the first one as well.

#######

I tried to make a loop to handle it, but it seems just to return the first page over and over again.

```
    i = 1
    my_url = "https://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=StoreIM&IsNodeId=1&bop=And&Depa=1&Category=38&Page={}&PageSize=12&order=BESTMATCH".format(i)
    while i <= 3: 
        uClient = uReq(my_url)
        page_html = uClient.read()
        uClient.close()
        page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

        # esse é o que vou usar para fazer o loop

        containers = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"item-container"})

        container = containers[0]


        for container in containers:
            title_container = container.findAll("a",{"class":"item-title"})
            product_name = title_container[0].text

            print("product_name: " + product_name)

        i = i+1
```

Does anyone can help me with that? =D

PS: Be free to change my code and propose a better solution, folks.
PS 2: Python 3.5 at Jupyter Lab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a loop in such a way so that the link you provide in your scraper rolls flawlessly.You can achieve the same in several ways. Here is one of them. Just execute the script and you will get all the product names traversing three pages.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

for page in range(1,4):
    my_url = "https://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=StoreIM&IsNodeId=1&page={}&bop=And&Depa=1&Category=38&PageSize=12&order=BESTMATCH".format(page)
    res = requests.get(my_url).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res, "lxml")
    for container in soup.select(".item-title"):
        print("product_name: {}".format(container.text))
```

Comment: Hey, @Shahin.  Thank you very much for your help. Yeah, it did work perfectly! I didi`t know all the packages you suggested me to use (lxml) so I tried some google to understand your code. 
But about my code, could you explain my what was going wrong? I can't understand why it was scraping the first page over and over. I did a loop to change, didn't I? 
btw: sorry for make you wait. I saw your post, but I was at work and I don't have Python there to try. =D

Comment: Comment deleted. Thanks.

Comment: I improved the code to look for more details:
Is it the better way to do so? (I tried to do two loops with "for"... it`s terrible to show without formation) ------- 
            for container in soup.select(".item-title"):
            print("product_name: {}".format(container.text))
        
            for shipping_container in soup.select(".price-ship"):
            print("shipping_const: {}".format(shipping_container.text))